# Understanding rapid, non-permanent phone screen degradation

Tags: display, amoled

This question arises because of a problem observed during a phone repair but it is not a repair question! I haven't a hope of repairing the display but I would like to understand the display and driver *design*. (My knowledge of display technology hasn't quite kept up with the times.)

I've replaced the broken screen on a Samsung 5M-J530F with an unbranded unit. (I've done this successfully on the same phone before!) There's a weird display problem that I don't understand.

On waking up the display everything appears normal for a few seconds.

[image]

*Figure 1. Display after wake-up.*

After a few seconds vertical white banding occurs in alignment with any white text or graphics on the display.

[image]

*Figure 2. Display after a few seconds. Note vertical stripes through the text.*

After the idle time-out the display fades to black but the white stripes remain.

[image]

*Figure 3. Fade to black.*

Switching apps causes the original stripes to fade away to be replaced by new ones matching the content of the new screen. Putting the display to sleep clears the stripes.

The phone's specification says that it's an AMOLED type. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMOLED),

[image]

> An AMOLED display consists of an active matrix of **OLED pixels** generating light (luminescence) upon electrical activation that have been **deposited or integrated onto a thin-film transistor (TFT) array**, which functions as a series of switches to control the current flowing to each individual pixel.

> Typically, this continuous current flow is controlled by at least two TFTs at each pixel (to trigger the luminescence), **with one TFT to start and stop the charging of a storage capacitor** and the second to provide a voltage source at the level needed to create a constant current to the pixel, thereby eliminating the need for the very high currents required for passive-matrix OLED operation. [Emphasis mine.]

Since the effect is not permanent and does a fade transition when switching screens my guess is that there is something affecting the storage capacitors on vertical lines with bright pixels on them - possibly a mismatch between the display driver and the display itself?

What failure mode can generate this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: What's rather odd about it is that it spreads vertically in *both* directions, which makes me suspect that the screen scans left-to-right, rather than top-down. Individual vertical lines might be getting a wrong bias of some sort.

Comment: Vague possibility: could it have to do with a burn-in prevention utility, https://reviewed.usatoday.com/televisions/features/most-oleds-have-built-measures-prevent-burn?